Cannot import shared enum type into nestjs project
I am building an app based on npm workspaces. My repo consists of: api (nestjs/mongo), frontend (react-native), and packages that are shared between these two apps. Can someone tell me why I cannot import an enum type from shared packages into my nestjs app?
An interesting fact is that I'm able to export any interfaces and types from that file except the enum.
project structure:
apps
|_ api
|_ mobile
packages
|_shared

user.schema.ts:
import { UserRoleDto } from '@dto/shared';

export type UserDocument = HydratedDocument<User>;

@Schema()
export class User {
...rest of code

@dto/shared:
export * from "./dto/comments.dto";
export * from "./dto/deals.dto";

users.dto.ts:
export enum UserRoleDto {
  customer = "customer",
  admin = "admin",
}

I getting a following error in console:
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

nestjs package.json:
  "dependencies": {
    "@dto/shared": "^1.0.0",
    ...

packages/shared package.json:
{
  "name": "@dto/shared",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
}

